# Display a repeater on data insert in ASP.NET web form using jquery without a postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This seems simple but I just cannot get it.
I have an asp.net page, with the following credentials:

1. 1 button
2. 1 textbox
3. 1 repeater

****Now when I type a text in my textbox, I passed the text to a web method using jquery ajax, 
which inserted the text into the database.
Now I have a public method in my code behind thta selects the data from the database and bind it to a repeater.
How do I display this this repeater on every data insert without a postback?****

```
 success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                $("#tbDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].ID + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].ChargeName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Description + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
```

Comment: CAPS LOCK MAKES EVERYTHING MORE READABLE

Comment: Why do you use an asp.net server control to display the data? Could you do another jquery ajax call and then display it in your html?

Comment: @hanlet hmm....how do i go about that?

Comment: I am working in a little sample for you and will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little sample, I guess you can ignore the Insert part since you said you already have it. This uses jQuery, which you also are using.

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function insertData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/insertData",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d != null)
                            alert(data.d);
                    }
                });
            }

            function retrieveData() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/retrieveData",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d != null) {
                            for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                                $("#myTable").append("<tr><td><input type='button' onclick='deleteRow(" + data.d[i].ID + ")' value='Delete'></input></td><td>" + data.d[i].Name + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].LastName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Age + "</td></tr>");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function deleteRow(ID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/deleteRow",
                    data: "{'row':'" + ID + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.d != null) {
                            alert(data.d);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            retrieveData();
        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <table id="myTable">
        </table>
    </asp:Content>
```

ASP.NET:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<SampleClass> retrieveData()
    {
        //Retrieve data from the server and return.
        List<SampleClass> tmp = new List<SampleClass>();

        tmp.Add(new SampleClass() { Name = "Test", LastName = "Number 1", Age = 44, ID = 1 });
        tmp.Add(new SampleClass() { Name = "Test", LastName = "Number 2", Age = 23, ID = 2 });
        tmp.Add(new SampleClass() { Name = "Test", LastName = "Number 3", Age = 20, ID = 3 });
        tmp.Add(new SampleClass() { Name = "Test", LastName = "Number 4", Age = 45, ID = 4 });
        tmp.Add(new SampleClass() { Name = "Test", LastName = "Number 5", Age = 21, ID = 5 });

        return tmp;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static bool deleteRow(int row)
     {
        if (row > 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static bool insertData()
    {
        //Do all of the insert in the server blah blah blah
        //and return true or false if it was inserted.
        return true;

    }
}

public class SampleClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Good luck!
Edit: Now you can also see a delete sample, which includes passing an argument to the webmethod. Good luck.

Comment: @hanlet....thanks for the details...but in the retrieveData web method, i want to return a repeater(not just a string)..i.e a query fetching data from the database and then showing it in the UI.

Comment: You want to return a repeater? I don't understand that part. What exactly are you getting from the database? Datatable, list of something?

Comment: The data.d object is a json object which can contain pretty much any strong typed object, or a datatable. I will create a strong typed object and modify my sample so that you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: @hanlet.....am returning data from a table in a database...but i bounded it to a repeater in code-behind.

Comment: @froodo, I updated the code a little to show you how to return a strong typed object from the code behind and display it on your html. Now, I understand that you are databinding the data to your repeater, but what exactly are you binding to your repeater? A datatable, a generic list of your object, a list of string? If you give me more info I may be able to give you a more detailed example.

Comment: @hanlet.....succesfully follwed your method and appended a table to the returned result....like this: in the dited code above.

Comment: @hanlet....how do i add a delete button to the first column of every row that will trigger a web method to  delete the row using the rowID column?...thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13822/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-froodo)